# Tools for real-time data visualization in a table?

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, hana

So this might be a bit of a strange one, but I'm trying to find a tool that would help me visualize real time data in a form of a table rather than a graph/chart. There are a lot of tools out there like Grafana, Kibana, Tableau that kind of fit a similar purpose, but for a very different application and they're primarily made for aggregated data visualization.

I am essentially looking to build something like what a departure board is at an airport. You got flight flight AAA that landed 20 minutes ago, XXX departing in 50 minutes, once flight AAA is clear it disappears from the departure board etc. Only I want to have that real-time, as the input will be driven by actions users are performing on the shop floor on their RF guns.

I'd be connecting to a HANA database for this. I know it's definitely possible to build it using HTML5, Ajax and Websocket but before I get on the journey of building it myself I want to see if there's anything out there that somebody else has already done better.

Surely there's something there already - especially in the manufacturing/warehousing space where having real-time information on big screens is of big benefit?

Thanks,

Linas M.

Comment: You can build your own tables on the web using javascript or jquery and set a refresh interval for the table depending on how frequently data gets updated. If you use a front end framework like react or angular the refreshes will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I think you might be looking for a **dashboard** solution.

Dashboards are used in many scenarios, especially where an overview of the past/current/expected state of a process is required.

This can be aggregated data (e.g. how long a queue is, how many tellers are occupied/available, what the throughput of your process is, etc.) or individual data (e.g. which cashier desk is open, which team player is online, etc.).

The *real-time* part of your question really boils down to what you *define* to be real-time.
Commonly, it’s something like *“information delivery that is quick enough to be able to make a difference”*.

So, if, for example, I have a dashboard that tells me that I will likely be short of, say, service staff tomorrow evening (based on my reservations) then to make a difference I need to know this as soon as possible (so I can call more staff for tomorrows shift). It won’t matter much if the data takes 5 or 10 minutes from the system entry to the dashboard, but when I only learn about it tomorrow afternoon, that’s too late.

Thus, if you’re after a dashboard solution, then there are in fact many tools available and you already mentioned some of them.

Others would be e.g. SAP tools like Business Objects Platform or SAP Cloud Analytics. To turn those into “real-time” all you need to do is to define how soon the data needs to be present in the dashboard and set the auto-refresh period accordingly.

Comment: Business Objects and Cloud Analytics neither has great real-time presentation of individual records, only aggregated data (and even then, the refreshing bit isn't fantastic)


I don't feel like any dashboarding solutions I've looked at give me quite what I need. Imagine a flight departure board - that's kind of what I'm looking to build, only for production. Dashboards are usually either not real-time enough, or just don't provide a great way to visualize real-time data in tables (while they do a great job at aggregating!)

Comment: What makes "great" or "fantastic" features really depends on your use case. I've worked on "real-time" dashboards that focussed on individual objects (intensive care units in my case) that used the mentioned tools and were very much up to the task. As the question is very open and vague it comes down to opinion, which is the reason to flag this question to close.